# How to reset the selected index dropdown value in html?

Tags: jquery, html

I need to set the selectedindex=0 for dropdown after submit form.
I tried like the below.

```
 $("#filterByName").prop('selectedIndex', 0);
 $("#filterByName").selectedIndex=0;
$("#filterByName").get(0).selectedindex=0;
```

but i am not able to acheive .please tell me how to reset the dropdown after submit form.

EDIT:
$('#filterByName')[0].selectedIndex .in that i am getting selected index value.after sumit click i am setting $('#filterByName')[0].selectedIndex=0 then this statement not setting showing the index 0 after click event.assigning but why in UI is not showing ?

```
<span id="filterByNames"><%= Html.DropDownList("filterByName", new SelectList(Model.Names, "Name", "Name", Model.Name), 
                                new { onchange = "filterByName()" }) %></span>
```

Please check my code and let me know how to reset the dropdown selected index after button click?

Comment: Please tell me my problem is not resolved.like the above i tried but dropdown index not resetting.

Answer (score 2):

**Html:**

```
<select id="test">
    <option value="1">Test</option>
     <option value="2">Test2</option>
</select>
```

**Jquery**:

```
$('#test').val("2")
```

Here is a [**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/z9hte/1)

http://jsfiddle.net/z9hte/1

in your case do like this:

```
$("#filterByName").val("0");
```

Comment: This is conceptually wrong. What if we have multiple select and each have different value in first option? Your solution won't work.

Answer (score 2):

After submit of form you can use like this

```
$('#submit').click(function(){

// after submit code

$('#filterByName option:selected').attr('selectedIndex',0);
return false;
});
```

Comment: no .i am not able to reset the dropdown selected value using the above

Comment: $('#filterByName option:selected').attr('selectedIndex',0); try this, assuming select drop down has id filterByName

Answer (score 0):

You can reset all the select using below code.

```
$('form select').each(function () {
    $(this).find('option').removeAttr('selected');
    $(this).find('option:first').attr('selected','selected');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$("#ddlList option:first-child").attr("selected","selected");
```

[Demo: Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6d27w/)