# How to change the selectedindex of the dropdown when button clicks in html?

Tags: jquery, html

I am not able to reset the dropdown after button click.please check this.

```
<span id="filterByApplication"><%= Html.DropDownList("filterByApplication", new SelectList(Model.App, "Name", "Name", Model.Name), 
                                new { onchange = "FilterByApplicationName()" }) %></span>
```

I quickly look at $('#filterByApplicationName')[0].selectedIndex and saw that I am getting selected value. I set selectedindex to 0 after button click but it's not effective. Please tell me.

$('#filterByApplicationName')[0].selectedIndex =0;

Comment: You already posted this question two hours earlier.  http://stackoverflow.com/q/23131977/122139

Answer (score 0):

Try this way :

Get dropdown value as:

```
$("#filterByApplication").val();
```

Set dropdown value as:

```
$("#filterByApplication").val(YOUR DROPDOWN VALUE);
```

Comment: i need to set the selectedIndex as default value.